# how to compress reducer output i mean (whole MR output ) to a zip.? instead of "part0000.txt " like "part0000.zip"

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to MR coding, can some one please help me ?
how to compress reducer output i mean (whole MR output ) to a zip.? in JAVA;
instead of "part0000.txt " like "part0000.zip"

Answer (score 0):

You could better configure mapreduce job properties to write the reducers' output itself as pre-compressed files.

The below properties will help you to do so,

```
mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress
mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec
mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type
```

You have variety of compression codecs and compression types available as per the OutputFormat that you have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

setting the following properties in the Configuration instance as listed below. However, when you run my job, the generated output by the reducer is compressed and the file generated name is: part-r-00000.gz.

```html
conf.setBoolean("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", true);
conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.typemapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec",   CompressionType.BLOCK.toString());
conf.setClass("mapred.output.compression.codec", GzipCodec.class, CompressionCodec.class);
```

For further details ...please follow [mapred-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)